# Vector Calculus Standard Text

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, book-recommendation

I'm considering two books to learn vector calculus at a level beyond that presented in standard calculus textbooks such as Thomas' or Stewart's, and more applied than a very rigorous text like Munkre's manifolds. Which one covers more advanced topics? Which one is more rigorous? Which one is more applied?

Marsden's or Colley's Vector Calculus?

Comment: For what it's worth, the Amazon reviews heavily favor Colley's text.  I myself used Colley's text and thought it was great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marsden's is a great textbook.

I used it for my multivariable calculus course and was of great help, lots of examples as well as applications in diverse fields!